# Products Category Tree - Product Quantity Inconsistencies

Tags: magento-1.6, quantity, category-tree

I've faced a strange situation in magento admin and haven't managed to find a proper answer for the issue.

Here it is:
[image]

As you can see for some reason numbers in brackets have completely no sense. One of them is not equal to the quantity in table (it is circled out). And it is completely unclear how the quantity for parent category is computed, cause at least it does not equal to the sum of its children's quantitties.

And so my question is: should I go deeper and try to find the reason for all of this or is it just strange, inexplicable but still normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your top level categories have is anchor set.
In the tree this will the represent the qty of all child categories included.

If you also assign products physically to that same anchor category, you will get the qty of assigned products to that category

Comment: Setting "is anchor" to "no" turned circled quantities to be the same, but other issues still present.